# what is char i=0x80 and why overflow did not happen in bit shifting

Tags: c

Here is  a program

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{ unsigned char i=0x80;
printf("i=%d",i<<1);
}
```

The output it is giving is 256.
I am not clear with what does

```
unsigned char i=0x80; <-- i is not int it is char so what will it store?
```

I know bitshift and hexadecimal things.
How is the value of i being stored and how does it gets changed to 256?

**UPDATE**

Why did overflow not occurred when the bit shift operation happened?

Comment: Google "hexidecimal" and "bitshift operators."

Comment: I know bitshift and hexadecimal but I am not able to understand what will unsigned char i store as it is not an int

Comment: @Registered User - `char` is an integral type. In C, character literals have type `int`. How do you know bitshift but not know that basic fact about C?

Comment: You are correct that 256 "overflows" an unsigned character (on x86 at least) -- the "magic" is you are not passing a "unsigned char" value ;-) Compare with `printf(..., (unsigned char)(128 << 1))`

Comment: @Registered - It **does** store the character whose ASCII value is 128. If you print it with `"%c"` you will see that (unless it is a non-printable character, which is likely).

Comment: @Bo Persson thanks Bo I got your point I checked it with printf before the bit shift I was not clear if unsigned char i= hexadecimal will actually do what people here had suggested.In this case after the bit shift the overflow did not happen can you guess any reason for the same?

Comment: @Registered - When you do `i << 1` that operation is performed on an `int`, which also matches the `"%d"` in the format string.

Comment: @Registered If you change the question after answers have been given, the answers become bad answers (here, not providing the simple explanation of why there is no overflow in your program).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C, a `char` is an integer type used to store character data, typically 1 byte.

The value stored in `i` is `0x80` a hexidecimal constant that is equal to `128`.

An arithmetic operation on two integer types (such as `i << 1`) will promote to the *wider* type, in this case to `int`, since `1` is an int constant.  In any case, integer function arguments are promoted to int.

Then you send the result to `printf`, with a `%d` format specifier, which mean "print an integer".

Answer (score 4):

I think that K&R have the best answer to this question:

> 2.7 Type Conversions When an operator has operands of different types, they
>   are converted to a common type
>   according to a small number of rules.
>   In general, the only automatic
>   conversions are those that convert a
>   `narrower'' operand into a`wider''
>   one without losing information, such
>   as converting an integer into floating
>   point in an expression like f + i.
>   Expressions that don't make sense,
>   like using a float as a subscript, are
>   disallowed. Expressions that might
>   lose information, like assigning a
>   longer integer type to a shorter, or a
>   floating-point type to an integer, may
>   draw a warning, but they are not
>   illegal. A char is just a small
>   integer, so chars may be freely used
>   in arithmetic expressions.

So i<<1 converts i to int before it is shifted.  Ken Vanerlinde has it right.

Answer (score 1):

`0x80` is hexadecimal for `128`. 
The operation `x << 1` means to left shift by one which effectively multiplies the number by two and thus the result is `256`.

Comment: @netrom all that I understand but the variable i is not integer it is a char so that is what I am not getting.

Comment: Also, since `printf` is variadic, the result is cast to an `unsigned int` rather than back down to `unsigned char` which would truncate the value.

Comment: @Registered User: An `unsigned char` is just an integer from `0` to `255`.

Comment: @netrom so you mean to say that i in this case will store the hexadecimal number and not the character 0x80

Comment: This misses out a vital piece of the question (that wasn't well illuminated): why is the value not wrapped to `0`?

Comment: The one thing missing in this answer is that the `x` is coerced to an `int` before the bitshift, so the result is also an integer, not an `unsigned char`. I think this is the biggest confusion presented in the question

Comment: The character that is equivalent to `0x80` (`€`), is stored.  The printf() statement is using %d, which tells the routine to print out the signed decimal value passed in.

Comment: @Reg: char is an integer, an 8-bit integer.  You are asking for the integer value of it to be printed when you use %d.  If you want to print a character use %c.

Comment: @pst: Maybe that is what he's asking.  The answer is that %d converts it to int.

Comment: @netrom I got your point unsigned char is treated as an integer and i is storing 128.That was what I was not clear.I know If I do char c='Z' then c will store ASCII value of Z in decimal number,I was not clear if same is applicable when you do unsigned char i= a hexa decimal no.In this case there is one more thing overflow did not happen after bit shift.Can you guess what is the reason for so?

Comment: @Reg: As Ken said, `x` is coerced from `unsigned char` to `unsigned int` right before the left shift. That is why no overflow occurred.

Comment: @reg you need to get rid of the misconception that the computer stores values in decimal or hexadecimal. It doesn't. It uses binary. These binary values can be represented as decimal or hex or character but to the computer they are just integer values stored as binary.

Comment: @David Hefferman thanks for this input how ever I want more information regarding the same so let me know if you have any link for the same.

Comment: @reg Do you have any books on programming?

Answer (score 0):

`i=0x80` stores the hex value `0x80` in i.  `0x80 == 128`.

When printing out the value in the `printf()` format statement, the value passed to the `printf()` statement is `i<<1`.

The `<<` operator is the unary bitwise shift left operator, which moves the bits in `i` to the left one position.

128 in binary is `10000000', shifting that to the right one bit gives '100000000' or 256.

Comment: Based on some previous comments, it appears there is some confusion in what is actually stored in an unsigned character value.  An unsigned character is simply an unsigned integral value of 8 bits.  You may be familiar with this holding ASCII characters (like 'a', or 'V'), but these are still stored as 8-bit integral values.

Comment: @Chad ok you mean to say in this case 0x80 is treated as a hexadecimal number and then converted to int i.e. 128 why does it not store the character whose ASCII value is 128

Comment: I have an upvote, but it would be nice if this discussed the *type* of evaluating `unsigned_char << 1` to round it out.

Comment: Err, 128 in binary is 10000000, shifting by 1 overflows the bounds of `unsigned char` on most platforms but due to `printf` being variadic it isn't cast back down.

Comment: The character whose ASCII value is `128` (`€`) is always stored as `0x80`, in fact they are equivalent.  Try a simple program that checks if `'€' == 0x80`

Comment: @Chris Lutz It doesn't have anything to do with printf being variadic -- the signature could be `foo(int bar)` and it would result in the same behavior. If the signature was `foo(unsigned char bar)`, then the compiler should (might?) provide feedback illuminating the problem.

Comment: @pst - But because `printf` is variadic, all types are cast up to an `int`. I also forgot that it's already cast up to `int` by the bitshift.

Answer (score 0):

i << 1 isn't being stored in i. Thus, there's no question of overflow and 256 is the output.

The following code will give 0 as the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{ 
    unsigned char i=0x80;
    i = i<<1;
    printf("i=%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0x80 is a hexadecimal constant
Which is equivalent to 128.
And  << is a left shift operator
Which says that if x<<y
Then x * (2^y).
So  128 * 2^1 (here y=1, the shifting value)
= 256.